# React Router v6 always thinks route is "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm trying to figure out the basics of React, and I can't find any explanation for the behaviour I'm seeing. When I try to use routes, the app acts as if the path is always "/": no route is ever matched other than path="/", and the console gives me the warning 'No routes matched location "/"'.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import {NativeRouter} from 'react-router-native';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NativeRouter> 
      <App /> 
    </NativeRouter> 
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-native';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      
      <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

function Home() {
  return (<div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <h2>Home View</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adip.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <h2>About View</h2>
      <p>ABOOOOUT.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried running this with `npm start` and expected a blank page for localhost:3000 and a page displaying "About View" for localhost:3000/about. The tutorial I copied most of this code from seems to suggest it should do exactly that.

Edit: for clarification, no matter what path I try, the page is always blank. The path "/about" does not work as intended.

Comment: There ***is*** not any route for `"/"` so I don't see how that would even be possible to match. The `"/about"` route should still work and render the `About` component though. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve? Do you just need to add a `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />` route?

Comment: Indeed there isn't any route for "/", but the "/about" route does not work, my code renders a blank page no matter what.

Comment: I see you are using the `NativeRouter`, how exactly are you navigating to `"/about"` to verify what is matched and rendered, or not?

Comment: By typing it into the URL bar. Does that only work for BrowserRouters? That'd figure, but I couldn't find anything saying so anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the `NativeRouter` in a web browser then you'll need to manually specify the initial route path to match and handle navigating around the app via links. `"/"` is the default initial route. The `NativeRouter` isn't coupled to the Browser's URL in the address bar the way the `BrowserRouter` is. This is similar to the way the `MemoryRouter` works.

See [NativeRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/native-router).

> ```
> declare function NativeRouter(
>   props: NativeRouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NativeRouterProps extends MemoryRouterProps {}
> ```

Example:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { NativeRouter as Router } from "react-router-native";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```
mport { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-native";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">
            <Text>About</Text>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-always-thinks-route-is]

[image: home page]
[image: about page]